# How to break a row into multiple rows based on a column value in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a Athena table that has a column containing array of values. I want to create multiple rows from one row such that the column of array can be changed to contain only 1 value.

E.g. :

```
Name   Id   PhoneNumber
Josh   123  [1236348475,5323794875]
```

to look like :

```
Name   Id   PhoneNumber
Josh   123  1236348475
Josh   123  5323794875
```

How can I write my query to achieve this?

Comment: also found more explanation here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [`unnest()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) does what you want:

```
select t.name, t.id, u.phonenumber
from t cross join
     unnest(t.phonenumber) u(phonenumber);
```